# blank screen when 21.10 finishes booting

Tags: boot, system-installation

I did a search here for this problem with 21.10 but didn't find anything.
Ubuntu 21.10 clean install
Installed Ubuntu to a USB using the Disk Creator utility and did a fresh install.
Everything went smoothly. It came to the end and asked to remove the drive and press “enter”. I did and it rebooted, showed the spinning circle along with the Ubuntu logo. Continued to boot and ended in a blank screen. I let it set for some time thinking it was loading other things but never the install never left the blank screen.
Tried a hard re-boot with the same results.
Tried downloading again, making the startup stick and reinstalling. Same result.
Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Still no resolution.

I found this searching for a way to upgrade the BIOS. So I don't think the BIOS is the problem.

"Ubuntu 16.04 and later natively notifies you of new BIOS updates. When an update is available, a notification is displayed to flash the update"

Comment: The *"showed the spinning circle along with the Ubuntu logo"* tells me that possibly Ubuntu didn't install correctly, or possibly, you have an older BIOS. How old is this computer? What video card? Show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the EXACT make/model of your computer or motherboard. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema The terminal shows F.35 when sudo dmidecode -s bios-version is run.

Comment: @heynnema The laptop is a HP : AV V1S43, Radeon™ R5 Graphics.

Comment: Is that the complete model #? I'm only seeing a F.30 BIOS... so I'm missing something. Go to https://support.hp.com and enter your serial # in the Software & Drivers support page, and see what you come up with.

Comment: @heynnema It said it was unable to find drivers for this product. It's a 17z-y000. It was purchased in December of 2016.

Comment: You need to select "Windows 10-64 bit" as the OS to see it. See my answer. If it solves your problem, please remember to accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**BIOS**

HP Notebook 17z-y000

**Note**: To see the BIOS update, you need to select "Windows 10-64 bit".

You have BIOS F.35. BIOS F.45 Rev.A is available [here](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-17-y000-notebook-pc-series/10862315/model/13200971).

**Note**: Have good backups before updating the BIOS

**Note**: Confirm the correct web page for your model #

Comment: You think a BIOS upgrade will do the trick then. An thanks I didn't know about having to pick the Windows system.

Comment: @BobB Hopefully. If not, we'll follow a possible video driver problem. Show me a screenshot of the `Software & Updates` **Additional Drivers** tab. If you can't fully boot, see my next comment.

Comment: @BobB At the GRUB screen, select your normal selection, then hit the "e" key to enter edit mode, find "quiet splash" and change it to "quiet splash nomodeset", then hit control-x or F10 to continue booting.

Comment: @BobB Do you dual-boot with Windows? If so, does that work?

Comment: How do I add a picture here? How do I boot into GRUB? I was trying to do that after the install of 21.10 but couldn't quite get it... Additional drivers says there are none available. I do not dual-boot, Only Ubuntu for years.

Comment: I need to step away for awhile. How do I add a picture here? How do I boot into GRUB? I was trying to do that after the install of 21.10 but couldn't quite get it... Additional drivers says there are none available. I do not dual-boot, Only Ubuntu for years. –

Comment: @BobB Are you able to boot right now? With or without nomodeset? If you don't have Windows (normally required to do BIOS updates), you have to check the current HP BIOS to see if you can update from there, or you'll have to try FreeDOS (http://www.freedos.org/).

Comment: Yes but I re-installed 21.04 in order to have something that worked. I am not running 21.10 as it boots to a blank screen. I was able to use 21.10 in the "try" mode but when I chose to install it it ran through the whole install then came to a dialog that said it couldn't complete and would open in a regular session in order to fix the problem.

Comment: @BobB *"dialog that said it couldn't complete and would open in a regular session in order to fix the problem"*... did it give any more detail than that? Later Ubuntu versions really need the latest BIOS, hence my recommendation. You may also have an issue with the AMD Radeon driver... so you'll have to check for a newer driver there too.

Comment: No it did not offer any other information. I just thought it odd that it would work just fine in the "try" mode but when installed would only end in a blank screen. I do not know how to update drivers or BIOS.

Comment: @BobB BIOS can be upgraded either 1) from the current BIOS, 2) from Windows, 3) FreeDOS USB stick. Driver for AMD needs to be checked at the AMD web site.

Comment: Looking as if a newer HP laptop might be in my future.....

Comment: This is interesting. I found it at the Ubuntu download site and it's a statement about 21.10. "Recommended system requirements are the same as for Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS." And that version worked just fine on this machine.

Comment: @BobB Figure out how to update the BIOS, and that may solve the problem.

Comment: @BobB Status please...